# Continuity of the identity map $I:(l^{1},\|.\|_{2})\rightarrow (l^{1},\|.\|_{1}).$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

If  $I:(l^{1},\|.\|_{2})\rightarrow (l^{1},\|.\|_{1})$(where $l^{1}$ is the vector space of all sequences $\{x_{n}\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum |x_{n}|<\infty , \|x\|_{1}=\sum_{n} |x_{n}|,\|x\|_{2}=(\sum_{n} |x_{n}|^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$) is the identity map, then

$A.$ Both $I$ and $I^{-1}$ are continuous.

$B.$ $I$ is continuous but $I^{-1}$ is NOT continuous.

$C.$ $I^{-1}$ is continuous but $I$ is NOT continuous.

$D.$ Neither $I$ nor $I^{-1}$ is continuous.

According to me as $(l^{1},\|.\|_{1})$ will gives weaker topology  than $ (l^{1},\|.\|_{2})$ so $I$ is continuous but not $I^{-1}.$ Am i right? Please give me some details for this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: these are standard norms in functional analysis....

Comment: The norms are obvious -- but the meaning of the inclusion $(l^{1},\|.\|_{1})\subset (l^{1},\|.\|_{2})$ is not. One has $l^1=l^1$, no?

Comment: @neelkant What is your argument about "weaker topology" /

Comment: Identity map from stronger topology to weaker topology  on the same set are continuous...

Comment: Not sure you are actually understanding the "topology" argument you added to the question. In such cases, where, obviously, you are lacking intuition, my advice would be to stick to examples: consider the sequences $x^{(n)}$ defined by $x^{(n)}_k=\frac1{n}$ if $k\leqslant n$ and $x^{(n)}_k=0$ otherwise. Does $x^{(n)}\to0$ for $\|\ \|_1$? For $\|\ \|_2$? Hence?

Comment: I'm not not asking that. How you say that $||.||_1$ gives weaker topology than $||.||_2$ ? What's your argument behind it ?

Comment: If $\sum_{n} |x_{n}| $ is convergent so is $\sum_{n}(x_{n})^{2}$

Comment: This question should be reopened. The question is clearly stated. Though the OP thoughts on the questions are not as clear as they could be, that is by no means a requirement of this site. I've posted a solution.

Comment: @TrialAndError yes sir i stated and write all standard notation and i got yours solution which i very clear and answered what i required...thank you very much....

Comment: @TrialAndError There is a distinct possibility that your action allowed the OP to **avoid** thinking about their own question. If this is so, we are at the opposite of the declared goal of the site.

Comment: @Did : I'm not inclined to close a nice question whose statement is clear when didactic methods fail. And, part of the fun for me is working on problems as well. I haven't studied Maths in 30 years, and honestly, I spend quite a bit of time thinking about questions here to keep my mind active. It's okay to be a little selfish, too, isn't it?

Comment: @TrialAndError You may decide to place yourself outside of the declared goal(s) of the site and to use it differently, but then I fail to understand your statement that  "This question should be reopened", supplemented by the frankly misleading "that is by no means a requirement of this site". Yes, "that" (i.e., context) is, by near consensus, very much "a requirement of the site". So, both pedagogically and with respect to the rules of the site, yes you are very much "selfish", it seems.

Comment: I Got the solution ...please now lets stop the discussion...  @Did  I will take care next time  to write the question in proper way ...

Comment: and @TrialAndError Thank a lot for yours precise time....

Comment: @Did : OP stated a clear question, and he gave his thoughts on the subject. I offered an answer. I do that all the time. I don't see anything outside the accepted practices here, but you're in a position to determine those goals, and if you feel that is outside proper behavior on this site, then I'll leave. Because I'm not going to change that for you.

Comment: @TrialAndError You change your arguments from comment to comment so indeed, there is not much point in having a discussion. Next time, perhaps refrain from posting wrong statements about the site.

Comment: @Did : What specific statement is a wrong statement about the site? Let me know and I won't repeat it.

Comment: @TrialAndError "This question should be reopened."

Comment: @Did : In what way did it not qualify to be reopened? I see a question with a multiple choice, and I see some thoughts on how to proceed. Is there something else required?

Comment: @TrialAndError Please stop trollng: I explained all this in my **first comment**. Since then you are engaged in some sort of damage control operation plus delaying tactics. Sorry but I am not interested.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: I've been accused of trolling and violating the rules of the site. A moderator's attention is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n$ denote the sequence with $1's$ in the first $n$ places, and $0$'s elsewhere. If $I$ were continuous, then there would exists a constant $M > 0$ such that
$$
            \|Ix_{n}\| \le M\|x_{n}\|,\;\;\;\\
                \|x_{n}\|_{\ell^1} \le M \|x_{n}\|_{\ell^2},\\
                  n \le M \sqrt{n}.
$$
This cannot hold for all $n$, which proves that **$I$ is not continuous.**

On the other hand, consider the natural map $\mathscr{I} : \ell^1 \rightarrow \ell^2$ that takes a sequence in $\ell^1$ to the same sequence in $\ell^2$. This map is between Banach spaces. And you can show that this map is closed because if $\{ x_n \} \subset \ell^1$ converges to $x\in\ell^1$ in the norm of $\ell^1$, and if $\{\mathscr{I}x_n\}\subset\ell^2$ converges to $y\in \ell^2$ in the norm of $\ell^2$, then $x=y$ follows because $\{ (x_n)_m \}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ that must converge to $x_m$, and must also converge to $y_m$. Hence $x=y$, which proves that $I^{-1}$ is closed. By the Closed Graph Theorem, $\mathscr{I}$ is a bounded operator. Hence **$I^{-1}$ is continuous.**

Comment: @neelkanth : You're most welcome. :)